# Python does not evaluate a function and let me run the code anyway

Tags: python, function, import, call

I have two Python files that share a common directory. One is called aux_functions.py and the other is called app.py. The app.py uses some functions of the aux_functions.py and I performed imports as always. However, the app.py file runs no matter the functions of aux_functions.py are misspelled. It does not detect the issue; therefore, the function does not acts as it is supposed.

I have tested the import part and misspelled the name of one function and the app.py detected the error. But, when I misspelled the name of the imported function inside another function of the app.py, the error is not noticed.

The aux_functions.py is like this:

```
def sign(k, m):
        do something

def format(a):
        do something
```

The app.py is like this:

```
from aux_functions import sign, format

def signature(data):
        mes = data["message"]
        sig = sign(key, mes)
        return format(sig)
```

It is expected that the app.py script uses the sign and format functions from aux_functions, but it does not do that. The import part is done, but the app is not using the functions. I tested by misspelling the **sign** function and put something like siggggggn in the app.py and it did not detect the error and ran anyhow. Therefore, the app.py script is not doing what I want.

How could I solve this? Is there anything related to one of the aux functions has a return and the other just formats a file? I thinks there is no rocket science in calling functions and working with them, but my app.py script is behaving weird. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: So `from aux_functions import siggggggn` can run even if `siggggggn ` is not defined in `aux_functions.py`?

Comment: If I put **from aux_functions import siggggggn** as trying to import, the app.py depicts an error saying that it is not found. BUT, when I put siggggn inside a function in app.py such script tell me no warning saying that siggggn does not exist even in aux_functions.

Comment: I do not get what you mean. Do you expect running `app.py` to raise an error? Why?

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't have overloading of functions.

With the `sign` function in `app.py`:

```
def sign(data):
    mes = data["message"]
    sig = sign(key, mes)
    return format(sig)
```

Here you call the function *recursively*. It calls itself, not the one from `aux_functions`.

To solve this you could import the whole module

```
import aux_functions
```

and then call `aux_functions.sign(key, mes)`.

Or use an alias for the `sign` function

```
from aux_functions import sign as aux_sign, format
```

and call as `aux_sign(key, mes)`.

Comment: Sorry Sir, I made a mistake in the explanation. the function is not being called itself recursively. The function in app.py has a different name from the one in aux_functions and it is like this:
   def signature(data):
       mes = data["message"]
       sig = sign(key, mes)
       return format(sig)
Even if I misspell the sign function from the aux file (I put ssssssssssign) the app.py runs without warnings which must say that sssssssssign is not found or something. I tried your suggestions, but the issue remains.

Comment: @OmarPhin *Edit your question!* And if an edit invalidates existing answers and comments, then consider deleting the question and writing a new one (as existing answers and comments will otherwise become wrong).